# Is there a way to import scss without the need of style?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, gatsby

I have a Gatsby app with scss.

At the moment I have the following :

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./mosaic.module.scss";
import Tile from '../tile/tile';

const Mosaic = (): JSX.Element => (
    <section className="wrapper style1">
        <div  className="inner">
            <h2 className="major">Smaller Projects</h2>
            <p>Here under follow minor projects, often unfinished; I show them anyway because they helped me widen my experience. :)</p>
            <section className={`${styles["features"]}`}>
                {[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(e => <Tile key={e}></Tile>)}
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
)

export default Mosaic;
```

If I do not import class from the module like this `className={`${styles["features"]}`}` it will not work.

But as you can see some className still work with `className="inner"`

This is because under gatsby-browser.js I imported some global css like this

`import "./src/styles/global.css"`

The problem is, it's really confusing to know when a class should be called with styles or in the normal way.

Is there a way to just use the default way for everything ? or opposite ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@PostgradExpat/using-gatsby-with-css-modules-and-scss-7e75a05533a4

Answer (score 2):

If you want regular global CSS, rename your file to `mosaic.scss`, import the file, and then apply your classNames as usual.

```
import "./mosaic.scss";
...
<section className='features'>...</section>
```

---

When you use the `*.module.scss` extension, you are actually telling `gatsby-plugin-sass` that you wish to use [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

If you wish to use CSS Modules, then you have to do:

```
import styles from "./mosaic.css";
...
<section className={styles.features}>...</section>
```

or

```
import {features} from "./mosaic.css";
...
<section className={features}>...</section>
```

---

Edit: After your clarification in the comments, I don't think `gatsby-plugin-sass` or `CSS Modules` do what you want. You might have better luck looking for another tool to handle your css (eg [stylable.io](https://stylable.io/))

Comment: but I believe this do not make the class scoped to the component

Comment: actually yes, I confirm that this make the scss not scoped to the component only

Comment: Sure. But you specifically asked `Is there a way to just use the default way for everything ?`

Comment: ah yes indeed, but I thought it was implied in the question that `Is there a way to just use the default way for everything ? (without loosing the current functionality) `

Comment: I understand now. I guess you are looking for something similar to the way that Angular's scoped styling works?